gitlab-backup create faile -> Backup::Error: gitaly-backup exit status 1
When I am using command  "gitlab-backup create --trace" to backup my gitlab data, the errors as follows:
{"level":"error","msg":"create: pipeline: 3 failures encountered:\n
- @hashed/18/d3/18d37c950a3e810d9b9a84c72c230ca16b7cec123456ef123456as1234567fe.git (dev/abc.com): manager: write bundle: remote repository: create bundle: rpc error: code = Internal desc = unexpected EOF\n - @hashed/2e/00/2e00b312b0a9681bef09f9085a4e918b8fceb0c0123456ef123456as1234567fe.git (dev/reports): manager: write bundle: remote repository: create bundle: rpc error: code = Internal desc = unexpected EOF\n - @hashed/b8/1d/b81d00e65f747a4161b56ab92f400b81862c2b123456ef123456as1234567fe.git (sts/matomo): manager: write bundle: remote repository: create bundle: rpc error: code = Internal desc = unexpected EOF\n","pid":2547819,"time":"2024-09-27T01:11:37.937Z"}

Backup::Error: gitaly-backup exit status 1
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/gitaly_backup.rb:49:in `finish!'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/targets/repositories.rb:33:in `dump'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/tasks/task.rb:25:in `backup!'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:57:in `run_create_task'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:145:in `block in run_all_create_tasks'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:145:in `each_value'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:145:in `run_all_create_tasks'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:32:in `create'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:12:in `block in create_backup'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:75:in `lock_backup'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:10:in `create_backup'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:117:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/rake:25:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/rake:25:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/cli.rb:455:in `exec'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/cli.rb:35:in `dispatch'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:584:in `start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/cli.rb:29:in `start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/exe/bundle:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.5.11/exe/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:create


I checked the relevant logs and didn't find anything suspicious. The errors I got from executing the command multiple times were all the same, but the repositories name and xxx.git address were different, so I think it has nothing to do with the data warehouse on gitlab.
The backup data is placed in the partition /dev/sdb1 divided from /dev/sdb. I don't know if this is related.
Before I upgraded gitlab to v17.4.0, the backup command was always normal.

This issue may be of interest to you - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/8738#note_2133515154
You can provide more context there.

I upgraded the version to the latest v17.4.2 and this issue did not reoccur!
